# Memory leak from curl library

Tags: c++, curl, openssh

Im having trouble, the below code compiles fine, but when I run it, after it outputs the file, I get a memory leak.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "include\curl\curl.h"
int main(void)
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.del.icio.us/dt");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "C:\\Users\\bryan\\GeoTrustGlobalCA.crt");
        /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */ 
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        /* Check for errors */ 
        if(res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                    curl_easy_strerror(res));

        /* always cleanup */ 
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am compiling it w/ gcc 4.7.0 on a windows vista machine using:

```
g++ -DCURL_STATICLIB testing.cpp -L lib -lcurl -lidn -lwldap32 -lssh2 -lz -lrtm -lcrypto -lgdi32 -lws2_32 -lwinmm -lssl -leay32 -liconv -o testing.exe
```

Any idea what might be causing this memory leak?

Comment: How are you detecting the leak? And why is this tagged C?

Comment: Im running the program, and before it finishes windows tells me that testing.exe has stopped working. I tagged it as C cause I am using the C api from curl. Thought maybe some C people might see the problem.

Comment: @bryan sammon: yeah, it's finished working. it doesn't mean that there is memory leak.

Answer (score 4):

You should try calling `curl_global_init` as described on this man page.  curl_easy_init() will call it for you but might result in problems in some cases.

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_init.html

Also call `curl_global_cleanup()`.

Comment: This worked for me. The leaks reported by valgrind went away.

Comment: @MarkLakata -- Excellent, can't say I remember answering this question from over 7 years ago, but I'm glad I did. :D

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked 3 years ago, but the problem still exists, so here's how one would deal with this issue. There is still reachable memory after `curl_global_init` and `curl_easy_init` and the [developers are aware of it](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.curl.library/24829). However, since it's not growing, there is no reason at the moment to fix it just to make valgrind stop complaining.

You can suppress these errors coming from curl with the following bit in your suppressions file.

```
{
   <insert_a_suppression_name_here>
   Memcheck:Leak
   match-leak-kinds: reachable
   ...
   fun:curl_global_init
   ...
}

{
   <insert_a_suppression_name_here>
   Memcheck:Leak
   match-leak-kinds: reachable
   ...
   fun:curl_easy_init
   ...
}
```

You can then use the suppressions file like so:

```
valgrind --suppressions=my_supp_file.supp my_binary
```

The errors will then show up as suppressed in your final report. e.g.:

```
==15518== LEAK SUMMARY:
==15518==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15518==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15518==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15518==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15518==         suppressed: 328 bytes in 11 blocks
```

As an aside, if you have other warnings you want to suppress, you can find out how to suppress them using valgrind's `--gen-suppressions` argument. See valgrind's manpage for more info.